# how to open print window after creating pdf in niklasravnsborg laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

I want A function that open the generated pdf in print mode directly..
Currently I can save my pdf and open it in new target window but how can i directly open pdf in print mode.

Below is my current code

To set protection, you just call the SetProtection() method and pass an array with permissions, an user password and an owner password.

The passwords are optional.

```
    use PDF;

    function generate_pdf() {
        $data = [
            'foo' => 'bar'
        ];
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.document', $data);
        $pdf->SetProtection(['copy', 'print'], '', 'pass');
        return $pdf->stream('document.pdf');
    }
```

Currently my pdf is open in new window and i get the option of download and print..but i want a function that can directly open in print pdf mode..

Comment: if you want to print directly. you should used javascript  `window.print(); ` but it doesn't work in pdf format

Comment: I have tried window.print(); also but it doesnt work

Comment: @JashalMehta did you find any solution?